# text rendering in qt 4.8.4

Tags: qt, text, rendering

I create QGraphicsTextItem and rotate it.
I use rendering flags

```
mMapView->setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::TextAntialiasing);
```

But the text item is good looking only when not rotated.

[image]

How to fix it?

Thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little bit tricky.
I assume you are working under Windows.

You must change the default hinting in file `...\src\gui\text\qfont_p.h` in line 75 to

```
... hintingPreference(QFont::PreferNoHinting)
```

Then you have to configure and compile the Qt Library with DIRECTWRITE on.

```
configure -opensource -debug-and-release -directwrite
nmake
```

(This solution didn't work with Windows XP)

Comment: @niels-franksen, thank you, your advice is too helpful! After execution your instructions i set letter spacing `font.setLetterSpacing(QFont::SpacingType::AbsoluteSpacing, 0.1);` and text becomes beautiful!
If i set letter spacing without recompilation with this params i have no effect. Sorry my english.

Comment: Next problem: Windows XP users cant run program, because Windows XP dont have DWrite.dll and cant work with it. How to make good looking fonts for Win 7 and Win 8 users and bad looking for Win XP? Is it possible?

Comment: Thanks to all, I will create new question for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you draw a line with 1 px width, the render will be fine horizontally or vertically. But with a angle like 45°, it will be ugly because of the aliasing (even with anti-aliasing).

It is the same issue with your text : the font size is too small to avoid aliasing.

You can fix that using a bigger text...

Comment: I need to use this(small) font. Microsoft Word can to rorate text without distortion!